# How to convert a Ghost Backup to a VM

Tags: conversion, backup, virtual-machine, ghost

I have ghost backup of my desktop. Now i want to use that Backup and create a VM for my personal Laptop.

How can i convert a Ghost Backup to a VM.

Can anybody done it already? Please, Can anybody help me out to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used VMWare Converter to convert my Desktop into a VM directly. Now my Desktop is on VM.

Comment: That'll only really work if you don't have .GHO files.

Answer (score 2):

I've done that in the past:

1. Set up a new virtual machine with a virtual disk large enough to comfortably fit the image (no need to install the OS) and set up booting priority in the virtual machine settings (enter BIOS setup by pressing Esc or F2)to boot the VM session from Ghost DVD or with a bootable media (USB for example) with Ghost executable files on it.
2. Connect an external USB HDD with the Ghost image on it to host computer (or use a DVD but then you have to boot from a USB unless your bootable CD with Ghost executables is an ISO image mounted in VMware settings as the first CD/DVD), then make sure the guest VM will see it (VM settings - devices) and boot the VM, start Ghost software and restore the image to the virtual disk. After the cloned file system boots in the virtual environment, its OS will detect the new virtual hardware and install  the necessary drivers.